# Exception cast in Eclipse Oxygen on startup in Ubuntu 17.04 with Oracle JDK

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

I've installed Eclipse Oxygen on Ubuntu 17.04 (x64).

When I open Eclipse Oxygen, I get an exception in the "Error Log" window, which can be seen below (snippet).

I've installed the Oracle JDK instead of the OpenJDK.

What could be the issue? How do I get rid of this exception?

```
!SESSION 2017-07-12 10:54:12.366 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.7.0.I20170612-0950
java.version=1.8.0_131
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.event 4 0 2017-07-12 10:54:21.723
!MESSAGE Exception while dispatching event org.osgi.service.event.Event [topic=org/eclipse/e4/ui/model/ui/UIElement/toBeRendered/SET] {ChangedElement=org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.basic.impl.TrimBarImpl@2f3928ac (elementId: org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar, tags: [], contributorURI: null) (widget: Composite {}, renderer: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.TrimBarRenderer@206e5183, toBeRendered: true, onTop: false, visible: true, containerData: null, accessibilityPhrase: null) (side: Top), org.eclipse.e4.data={ChangedElement=org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.basic.impl.TrimBarImpl@2f3928ac (elementId: org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar, tags: [], contributorURI: null) (widget: Composite {}, renderer: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.TrimBarRenderer@206e5183, toBeRendered: true, onTop: false, visible: true, containerData: null, accessibilityPhrase: null) (side: Top), AttName=toBeRendered, EventType=SET, OldValue=false, Widget=null, NewValue=true}, AttName=toBeRendered, EventType=SET, OldValue=false, Widget=null, NewValue=true} to handler org.eclipse.e4.core.di.internal.extensions.EventObjectSupplier$DIEventHandler@2cdb53d6
!STACK 0
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setLocation(Control.java:1219)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets.ImageBasedFrame.setFramedControlLocation(ImageBasedFrame.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets.ImageBasedFrame.access$0(ImageBasedFrame.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets.ImageBasedFrame$4.controlMoved(ImageBasedFrame.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5252)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1348)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1374)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setBounds(Control.java:1134)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setBounds(Composite.java:1511)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ToolBar.setBounds(ToolBar.java:589)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setLocation(Control.java:1221)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets.ImageBasedFrame.setFramedControlLocation(ImageBasedFrame.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets.ImageBasedFrame.access$0(ImageBasedFrame.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets.ImageBasedFrame$4.controlMoved(ImageBasedFrame.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5252)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1348)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1374)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setBounds(Control.java:1134)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setBounds(Composite.java:1511)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ToolBar.setBounds(ToolBar.java:589)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setLocation(Control.java:1221)
```

Comment: Looks like Eclipse bug [511345](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=511345) no resolution is listed.

Comment: So, it will be fixed in future?

Comment: I am not a Eclipse developer so I can't answer that